# Facebook JavaScript SDK: FB.Data.query

Tags: javascript, facebook, sdk

I'm using the Facebook JavaScript SDK with a `FB.Data.query` object. I'm currently doing something like this:

```
var query = FB.Data.query('select blah from blah where uid={0}', exampleUID);
query.wait(function(rows) {
    // do some cool shit here...
});
```

I want to know if there's a way to detect an error (such as a syntax error) in the query itself. Something like:

```
query.error(function() {
    throw 'FAIL!';
});
```

Is this possible?